# Receiving XML from HTTP Post

Tags: java, xml, apache, restful-url

So I have the following code:

```
    public void SendToApplication(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, TransformerException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("CreatePoll.xml")));
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while((line=br.readLine())!= null) sb.append(line.trim());

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/cs9322.simple.rest.doodle/rest/polls/comment");
        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(sb.toString());
        input.setContentType("text/xml");
        postRequest.setEntity(input);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    }
```

Which reads a XML file (CreatePoll.xml),

```
<Comment xmlns:xs="http://localhost:8080/cs9322.simple.rest.doodle/CommentSchema">
  <Poll_ID>2</Poll_ID>
  <Name>Bob</Name>
  <Text>testing junk</Text>
  <Timestamp>2012-10-14T12:37:04</Timestamp>
</Comment>
```

And posts it to a web service, the problem I am having now is trying to receive the XML response from the web service after sending that. XML I am meant to receive is:

```
<comment>
    <address>
    </address>
</comment>
```

Can someone help me out here it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: you should never be reading xml using a Reader (or converting it to a String).  you should be using an InputStream and treating to xml data as bytes so that you don't accidentally break the character encoding.  same for handling the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you utilize the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/index.html), then you can use the `IOUtils` class to read the input stream from the `HttpEntity`. Example using the twitter Rest API:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=elkstein&count=5");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String body = IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8");
```